# "Remove all commits" when a commit added is not working after adding a new commit

Tags: gitlab, merge-request, gitlab-ee

I'm currently facing an issue with GitLab merge requests in self-hosted gitlab.

**Description of the Problem:**

- "Remove all commits" when a commit added is not working after adding a new commit.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Create a branch
2. Create a commit
3. Approved it
4. Create a commit to the
   same branch

**Expected Behavior:**

- The MR approves should be deleted

**Actual Behavior:**

- The MR approves are not deleted after adding a new commit.

**Additional Information:**

- Gitlab version is v16.7.3-ee
- Gitlab plan is Ultimate

Comment: Interesting idea to format SO-questions like a github issue. Maybe it should be an issue.

Comment: What is an MR in your context?

Comment: MR is Merge Request